# JS - how to use qunit to test

Tags: javascript, testing, qunit

We have JS API does many things based on the HTML (markup semantics and CSS). We have many codes like this one below:

```
function initHelpText() {
    $(".helpText, .tooltip, #pageHelp").css("cursor", "hand");
}
```

Don't worry about what the code does, just an example. Now how I do use qUnit to test, this functionality works. My guess is that I need to set some HTML elements with above classes and some how I need to test this, correct? I understand what qUnit does, but for sure am missing something pretty basic. Could you please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is test for one element

```
test('.helpText cursor test',function(){
   var element = $('<div class="helpText"></div>');
   $('body').append(element);
   same($('.helpText').css('cursor'),'hand','Cursor should be hand');
   element.remove();
});
```

Comment: I guess I understand now. Thanks, now I see big picture.

Answer (score 1):

OK...I thought it is a basic question, sounds like not many people are using qUnit and people who use may be don't have exact situation.

For anyone who gets to this situation, I ended up putting my own HTML beyond qUnit's stat HTML. It looks ugly -- hey it works. Thanks.